Edit summary rejected with "Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment."
I recently tried to submit an edit to Why does an invariant measure define a Schwartzman cycle? No matter what I put in my edit summary, it was rejected with the message "Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment."


A corresponding bug report on [meta.se]: "Comment reserved for system use" when trying to edit with an edit summary

As mentioned in that post (and in the MO chatroom), if the edit summary is left empty, the edit still goes through. (Which is definitely far from optimal - but at least it is some kind of workaround - until it is fixed properly.)

Thanks, @MartinSleziak!  Something went wrong over here, too; when I tried to post this question, I got a 404 page.  I didn't even know it had posted until I saw your comments and the link you posted in chat.

Resolved on this MSE post

Sorry for the bump, but I wanted to get this off the unanswered questions list.  (Does that exist for MMO?)  @Slate commented that this has been resolved.
